# why did tomcat not start while the docker container started success?

Tags: docker, tomcat, containers

**tomcate and jdk downlowded from their official websites**

Following is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos
MAINTAINER jachen<1862457@qq.com>
COPY readme.txt /usr/local/readme.txt

ADD jdk-8u261-linux-x64.tar.gz /usr/local/
ADD apache-tomcat-9.0.22.tar.gz /usr/local/

#RUN yum -y install vim

ENV MYPATH /usr/local
WORKDIR $MYPATH

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_261
ENV CLASSPATH $JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar

ENV CATALINA_HOME /usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.22
ENV CATALINA_BASH /usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.22

ENV PATH $PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$CATALINA_HOME/lib:$CATALINA_HOME/bin

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["/usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.22/bin/catalina.sh" "run"]
```

Build command :

```
docker build -t diytomcat3:0.3 .
```

start command:

```
docker run -it -d diytomcat3:0.3 /bin/bash
```

then go inot the docker:

```
[root@localhost ~]# docker exec -it cb4aebe4a834 /bin/bash
[root@cb4aebe4a834 local]# pwd
/usr/local
[root@cb4aebe4a834 local]# curl localhost:8080
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused
[root@cb4aebe4a834 local]#
```

that means tomcat luanch failed.

but when run catalina.sh run, then the tomcat could launch success:

```
[root@cb4aebe4a834 local]# catalina.sh run
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.22
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.22
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.22/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_261
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.22/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.22/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
24-Aug-2020 13:41:10.011 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.22
.....
24-Aug-2020 13:41:12.668 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
24-Aug-2020 13:41:12.676 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [1,625] milliseconds
```

and I tried to get some logs, but got nothing:

```
[root@localhost ~]# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
cb4aebe4a834        diytomcat3:0.3      "/bin/bash"         9 minutes ago       Up 9 minutes        8080/tcp            happy_thompson
[root@localhost ~]# docker logs cb4aebe4a834
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Comment: You're missing a comma in `CMD ["/usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.22/bin/catalina.sh" "run"]` (that should be `CMD ["/usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.22/bin/catalina.sh", "run"]`)

Comment: Also your command `docker run -it -d diytomcat3:0.3 /bin/bash` overrides your CMD with `/bin/bash`.

Comment: thank you , larsks  and   Konrad Botor !!  you resolve my problem, it made me the last weekend unhappy, thank you very much~!!!!!!!

Comment: Another error: `CATALINA_BASH` schould be `CATALINA_BASE` instead.